# Canonical "orientification" of a manifold? Canonical complexification of a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory

Maybe this is a silly question(i'm pretty new to both geometry and category theory) but i was wondering:

1)Consider the category of orientable smooth manifold on $\mathbb{R}$, if you forget the orientable structure and goes to the category of smooth manifold you get a forgetful functor F. Does F have an adjoint G? Would this correspond to constructing a kind of canonical orientable manifold associated to a given one? When this operation could be useful?

2)The same question of 1), forgetting the complex structure of complex manifolds and going to real analityc manifolds.Would this correspond to constructing a kind of canonical complex manifold associated to real analytic ones?When this operation can be useful?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: What are the morphisms in each case?

Comment: Smooth map in the first case(for both categories) and in second case holomorphic map for complex manifold in the first category and analityc maps for analytic manifolds in the second category. Maybe in the first case one can restrict also the map between orientable manifolds, and maybe this gives different answer. I'm curious to hear about it.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't think that will work. The closest thing I know of for (1) is the orientation bundle of a manifold, but that won't work if you use smooth maps for both categories. Perhaps you should use _orientation-preserving_ smooth maps on one side...

Comment: @ZhenLin Do you mean the orientable double cover? If so, that seems like the most natural choice to make (but I agree the maps need to be more restrictive).

Comment: @Zhen Lin:the restriction on taking orientation preserving maps seems very natural. I've seen on wikipedia this double cover(if you meant that as Daniel Rust asked), and it seems also to me a plausible choice. I'll try to figure out a proof or a disproof of your proposal for 1)(with the restriction on morphisms to orientation preserving ones for the oriented category).